# Display three different color/text in one by one in each visit and in loop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

```
if(localStorage.getItem("attempts")==1) {
//Show Red color
 alert('1')
}
if(localStorage.getItem("attempts")==2) {
//Show Black color
 alert('2')
}
if(localStorage.getItem("attempts")==3) {
//Show white color
 alert('3')
}
var attempts = Number(localStorage.getItem("attempts"));
localStorage.setItem("attempts", ++attempts);console.log(attempts);
```

- I need to show three different color on different visits in circular.
  for example 1st visit - Red, 2nd visit- Black, 3rd visit- white and again on 4th visit it should start from RED, 5th-WHITE, 6th-BLACK etc..

Comment: A single **=** is a value assignment, A double **==** checks if the first opperand is equal to the second. In JS there is even a tripple **===** which is the strict equal comparison. Where **"0" == 0**  returns true (comparison between string and number type), **'0'===0** returns false, because of the different types.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like example below? You will need to adjust it by adding localstorage.

```js
let clicks = 0;
let element = document.getElementById('color');
let btn = document.getElementById('clickbtn');

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clicks++;
  switch (clicks) {
    case 1:
      element.style.color = 'red';
      break;
    case 2:
      element.style.color = 'green';
      break;
    case 3:
      element.style.color = 'blue';
      break;
  }
  if (clicks == 3) clicks = 0;
});
```

```html
<button id="clickbtn">Click</button>
<p id="color">color element</p>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem('attempts')) {
    localStorage.setItem('attempts', 0)
  } else {
    let fetchedAttempts = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('attempts'))
    fetchedAttempts++
    localStorage.setItem('attempts', fetchedAttempts)
  }
})

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let attemptsCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('attempts'))

  if (attemptsCount % 3 === 1) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'
  } else if (attemptsCount % 3 === 2) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'black'
  } else if (attemptsCount % 3 == 0) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'white'
  }
})
```

Comment: i need to repeat in loop like on 4th visit it should start from red, white and black. it's counting only 1.

Comment: for that you need one more key in `localStorage` that track `color` and then on `DOMContentLoaded` you need to fetch that key and put the value equal to `document.body.style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: instead of color tried alert also but not worked kunal.

Comment: try the code now!!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment, you have an error in your comparison. You use the single = (a value assignment) instead of == or === a comparison.

In order to cycle through your colors while still counting the requests up, use the modulo operator: %

This calculates the remainder after division. For example `7 % 3` calculates the remainder after dividing 7 by 3 which is 1.

That way you can count up and change the color based on the rest of your division which is always either 0, 1 or 2

```
let count = 0
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  if (!localStorage.getItem("count")) {
    localStorage.setItem("count", count);
  } else {
    let fetchedCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"));
    fetchedCount++;
    localStorage.setItem("count", fetchedCount);
  }
});

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  let visitingCount = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("count"));

  if (visitingCount % 3 === 1) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  } else if (visitingCount % 3 === 2) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "black";
  } else if (visitingCount % 3 == 0) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }
});
```

Comment: @Sai It solved your problem!!